# Just format HDD in ext4, cannot create any folder

Tags: 16.04, permissions, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4

I have secondary internal HDD, to larger files and download (OS is in SSD).
I just formatted it with ext4 filesystem.
Now I cannot create any folder, nor set any application working to it (trasmission, jd2, etc.).
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Few months ago I tried another time, but then I formatted it in NTFS.
In terminal I do `lsblk`:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0 931,5G  0 part /media/sassari74/eaae11b1-a939-4674-a5a7-6e0357
sdb      8:16   0 223,6G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   353M  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0   124G  0 part 
├─sdb5   8:21   0  91,6G  0 part /
└─sdb6   8:22   0   7,7G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Did you change the ownership of the mount point after formatting?

Comment: No. Also because I do not know how to do it..

Comment: Ok, do you know where the partition is mounted now? If not, run `lsblk` in a terminal and add the output to the question, please.

Comment: Is your new filesystem mounted? To find out, do "mount | grep DEVICE" where DEVICE is the name of the partition it is on like "/dev/sda1" or whatever. If you aren't sure of the device run "sudo blkid" and study the output. It'll be in there somewhere. ADDED BY EDIT: I think I'll leave you in the capable hands of Fast Fingers Muru, because anything I slowly type he will have covered before I click the button. ;-)

Comment: And BTW, if you haven't already, you might want to add the new filesystem to /etc/fstab. Study "man fstab".  You can make mounting with r/w perm for the filesystem automatic on boot if you like.  Or not automatic, but easier (meaning less typing) to mount manually, requiring password entry or not as you choose, etc. Fstab is worth learning.

Comment: Try creating a folder as root. `sudo mkdir <your/path>/foo`

If this works, somehow you, the user, are unable to get r/w privileges. In that case, try `sudo chown <username> <partition/or/directory>`

You could also try launching your file manager (`nautilus` on Unity and `caja` on MATE Desktop) as root. Try: `sudo nautilus path/to/directory`

Let us know which of these, if any, work for you and it will be easier to identify the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like the partition you're talking of is `/dev/sda1`, and it is mounted at `/media/sassari74/eaae11b1-a939-4674-a5a7-6e0357`, so do:

```
sudo chown $USER /media/sassari74/eaae11b1-a939-4674-a5a7-6e0357 -R
```

This should set the ownership to you and you should then be able to create and modify files in it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!  Just a last question: does it last forever? Thanks!

Comment: @GianfrancoL. until you chown again or move to another system with different UIDs for your user.

Comment: oook, have a nice day.

Comment: why `chown`? why not `sudo chmod a=rwx -R`? and keep root as owner?